# Does NVelocity support foreach.count?

Tags: castle-monorail, castle, nvelocity

I'm using the [NVelocity](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html) from the Castle project and according to the [velocity specs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/vtl-reference-guide.html#aforeach_-_Loops_through_a_list_of_objects) I should be able to access the loop counter like this:

```
$foreach.counter
```

But I can't get it to work so I suspect that it has not been implemented in NVelocity.

Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's implemented, but it's called `$velocityCount`

Comment: Thanks! just for reference, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @Ola: it's actually in the old velocity specs: http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/vtl-reference-guide.html it seems that java velocity has recently changed this.